# PostgreSQL query to merge two tables based on range of dates

Tags: postgresql

I would like to merge two tables by range of dates.
For each employee in table 2 I will lookup the value in table 1 within the date range.
If I found one value I update, if I found more I will create a new row.

```
Table_1
Employee    start_date  end_date    value
1           1990-01-01  2019-11-24  false
1           2019-11-25  2019-11-26  true
1           2019-11-27  2020-01-01  false

Table_2
Employee    start_date  end_date    value
1           1990-01-01  2018-12-31  J1
1           2019-01-01  2020-01-01  J2

Merged
Employee    start_date  end_date    value   value
1           1990-01-01  2018-12-31  J1      false
1           2019-01-01  2019-11-24  J2      false
1           2019-11-25  2019-11-26  J2      true
1           2019-11-27  2020-01-01  J2      false
```

I've tried to get all the combinations with an union all and get each time the minimum date but it's not working

```
 select least(t1.startdate, t2.startdate), least(t1.enddate, t2.enddate), t2.value, t1.value from table_2 t2
 left join table_1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.startdate between t1.startdate and t1.enddate
 union all
 select least(t1.startdate, t2.startdate), least(t1.enddate, t2.enddate), t2.value, t1.value  from table_2 t2
 left join table_1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id and t1.startdate between t2.startdate and t2.enddate

1990-01-01  2018-12-31  J1  false
1990-01-01  2019-11-24  J2  false
1990-01-01  2018-12-31  J1  false
2019-01-01  2020-01-01  J2  false
2019-01-01  2019-11-26  J2  true
```